# How to make localstorage of focus in textbox using Jquery dynamic?

Tags: javascript, jquery, textbox, local-storage

```
 <input id="input1" type="text" />
 <br />
 <input id="input2" type="text" />
```

I have followed this simple script that stores the focus on the input text.

```
      $(document).ready(function() {
        changeFocus();
        $("#input1").click(function(){
        localStorage.setItem('txtObjectid', "input1");
        changeFocus();
        return false;
       });

      $("#input2").click(function(){
        localStorage.setItem('txtObjectid', "input2");
        changeFocus();
        return false;
       });
       });

 function changeFocus(){
   if(localStorage.getItem('txtObjectid')==null)
       id="input1"
       else
           id=localStorage.getItem('txtObjectid');
   var v = "#" + id;
   $(v).focus();
}
```

What I want to learn/know about is how to make the script flexible? How could I make this so that it won't search of the id = "input1" instead it will search for input[type=text]?

Comment: Ahem. $("input[type=text]")  perhaps?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this should do it

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var id = 'input1';
    if (localStorage.getItem('txtObjectid')) {
        id = localStorage.getItem('txtObjectid');
    }

    $('#' + id).focus();

    $('input[type="text"]').on('focus', function () {
        localStorage.setItem('txtObjectid', this.id);
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/7rW8w/1/)

Comment: so I should just discard the function changefocus?

Comment: @user3230425 - Seemed like a strange function to run everytime you click an input ?